# I cannot get the value stored into a variable after session_unset()

Tags: php, session

I cannot get the value stored into a variable after `session_unset()`.

```
echo $salt = $_SESSION['salt']; //ok here
session_unset($_SESSION['salt'])
echo $salt; //i cannot get the value here
```

I am using php 5.3.26. It was working fine on php 5.6 in local.

Comment: yes but it showed fine. the value was stored there.

Comment: Do you know what `session_unset` do?

Comment: yes a little. but what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

```
unset($_SESSION['name']); // will delete just the name data
```

you can use this code:

```
$salt = $_SESSION['salt'];
echo $salt;
session_unset($_SESSION['salt'])
echo $salt;
```

Also, `session_unset();//clear all session data` takes no arguments.

If you only want to unset `$_SESSION['name']`, then just do `unset($_SESSION['name'])`.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)

Comment: correct me if i am wrong. I think in my code the variable `$salt` must already have stored the session value irrespective of whatever I do to my session. The value must be in the variable. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

`session_unset()` removes values from `$_SESSION`. Unset your session after processing values.

Answer (score 0):

Once You do session_unset() that session got destroy so you cant get value of it.
Destroy your session once you use it